# 'Cordova/CDV.h' file not found when building ios app Cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, extjs

I am having trouble building an iOS version of my app using cordova on a Mac. When I run this command for android on the same machine, I get a success message,

```
cordova build android 

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1 mins 53.473 secs
Built the following apk(s): 
    /Volumes/data/app/webapp/cordova/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
```

But if I try to generated for iOS with this command, I get an error a shown below.

cordova build ios

```
/Volumes/data/app/webapp/cordova/platforms/ios/TheApp/Plugins/cordova-plugin-device/CDVDevice.m:24:9: fatal error: 
      'Cordova/CDV.h' file not found
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>
        ^
1 error generated.

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fliapfgngglxfnbapiyopwlziapf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o MyApp/Classes/AppDelegate.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC /Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fliapfgngglxfnbapiyopwlziapf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MainViewController.o MyApp/Classes/MainViewController.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC /Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fliapfgngglxfnbapiyopwlziapf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVDevice.o MyApp/Plugins/cordova-plugin-device/CDVDevice.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(3 failures)
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Volumes/data/app/webapp/cordova/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,TheApp.xcworkspace,-scheme,TheApp,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6s Plus,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Volumes/data/app/webapp/cordova/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Volumes/data/app/webapp/cordova/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
Users-MacBook-Pro:cordova User$
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying so many ways with no success I ran:

```
cordova platform update ios
```

This fixed it for me. (XCODE 7.3.1, Cordova 6.3.0)

Comment: Well, This worked perfectly @Ved, Its strange because I had the same version of cordova it updated to.

Comment: Sounds Good @IsaacChambers